# Getting the center of a group of points

Tags: vector, coordinates

I have a group of points in a two dimensional field. Here's a simplified image of the situation (Yes, really simplified):

i imgur com/UcZ9TwR png (2 rep short; could someone fix this for me)

I found out that something called mean vector could be used by googling. But googling what a mean vector is found me all sorts of different but difficult looking formulas. Could anyone explain it verbally to me?

Comment: You can build the mean vector using the mean of each of the two coordinates of your dataset, that's it. The fact that it overlaps more complicated definitions is due to higher dimension problems. It's worth checking the definition of isobarycenter though.

Comment: That's it! I feel so stupid now.